# OrCAD - Splitting signals

Tags: orcad

how can I split signals like in the picture below in OrCAD? I was trying to find it, but unsuccessfully.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are voltage ports and its essentially like drawing a wire between two points. If you need another point, just add one with the same name or attach another set with a different name to the same node.